# How to perform Statified random sampling for supervised classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, sampling, random-forest

I want to select my training points using stratified sampling. When I run the code, there is an error saying "unrecognized argument".
Can someone look at my code and help me find the issue with the script?

```
//B) LOAD L8 for 2020: 


var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
    .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')  //extend year range 
    //.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,3,'month'))  //include dry season months 
    .filterBounds(ROI) 
    .map(clipfunction)    //only show landsat for ROI
    .map(mask_Elevation)  // only show landsat for areas above a certain elevation
    .map(maskL8sr);        //cloud mask for the ROI
print(landsat8)

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000, gamma: 1.4 };
Map.addLayer(landsat8.median(), visParams, 'landsat_ROI');
Map.centerObject(ROI, 6); 

var FCmerged=water.merge(urban).merge(plantation).merge(barrenland).merge(mangrove).merge(nonMangrove); 
Map.addLayer(FCmerged, {}, 'FCMerged'); 

//Stratified Random Sampling: 

var FCimage=ee.Image().byte().paint(FCmerged, "LC").rename("LC")
print(FCimage, 'image'); 

var stratifiedsample=FCimage.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints:1000, 
  classband:"LC",
  region:ROI,
  scale:10, 
  classValues:[0,1,2,3,4,5], 
  classPoints:[100,100,100,100,100,100],
  geometries:true
}) 
print('Stratified samples', stratifiedsample); 
print(stratifiedsample.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['LC']).get('histogram','No of points'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what part of the code gives the error I would guess that one of your arguments in stratifiedSample is incorrect. Check the Spelling. classband should be classBand.

Can you provide is with a reproduceable example next time? Also did you check other questions here on StackExchange?

Comment: It was the spelling error. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I shall try to post a reproducible script next time, thank you